# What is relation between Star and God?

Tags: worship, gods, festivals, nakshatra

AFAIK, Rig veda says, every star is related to a God and hence everyday is special day(festival) to worship a specific god, what are those stars and to which god does they relate to?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the Rig Veda talks about each star being related to a god?  You can read the Rig Veda here; it doesn't discuss that subject at all: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/index.htm The oldest texts that discuss astronomy/astrology are the Shulba Sutras and the Vedanga Jyotisha.

Comment: To clarify do you mean birth stars, or every star in the sky?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan 27 birth stars. I heard that from a pundit.

Answer (score 1):

There are 27 Star ( Nakshatra ).

They are,

```
Ashvinī
Bharanī
Kṛttikā
Rohinī
Mrigashīra
Ārdrā
Punarvasu
Pushya
Ashlesha (nakshatra)
Maghā
Pūrva Phalgunī (Pubbha)
Uttara Phalgunī (Uttara)
Hasta
Chitrā
Svātī
Vishākhā
Anurādhā
Jyeshtha
Mūla
Pūrva Ashādhā
Uttara Ashādhā
Shravana
Dhanistha
Shatabhisha
Pūrva Bhādrapadā
Uttara Bhādrapadā
Revatī
```

You can say all these are देवता (devta) but not god (bhagwan).

To know more [Nakshatra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakshatra).

Comment: I'm trying to learn which star is connected to which god, I'm not saying star is a god

Comment: @pbvamsi - The followong stars are associsted with their rrspective deities.     Shravana -> Vishnu, Arudra->Siva, Uttara -> Goddess Lakshmi, Rohini -> Krishna, Swati->Narasimha, Punarvasu -> Raama

Comment: @Krishna What is the reason that Shravana Nakshatram is associated with Vishnu?  If you know the answer, you can answer my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3058/36

Comment: @Krishna Please post your comment as an answer. Add more information if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer by *Saurabh Chandra Patel* incomplete. Some of the *Nakshatras* are named after Devatas etc. For example, the *Ashwini* twins are considered as *Devatas*. Although, most of the Nakshatras are not e.g, Mula, Purva Ashadha, Hasta etc. *Hasta* means hand, *Mula* means root and these are not Devatas in itself.

> In *Jyotisha*, most Nakshatras are considered to be associated with
>   ***presiding deities***. This can be considered as the relatoionship between these stars and the Gods. In addition to that, they are ruled by
>   ***different planets which are also considered Gods.***

This list provides the name of the Nakshatra followed by the presiding deity followed by the ruling planet (in some cases, only the ruling planet is mentioned):

> Ashvini * Ketu
>
> Bharani * Shukra * Venus
>
> Krittika * Surya * Sun
>
> Rohini * Brahmi * Chandra * Soma
>
> Mrigashirsha * Mangala
>
> Arudra * Rahu
>
> Punarvasu * Yamaka * Guru
>
> Pushyami * Sidhya * Shani * Saturn
>
> Azlesa * Naga * Budha * Mercury
>
> Magha * Pitri * Ketu
>
> Purva-phalguni * Yoni* Shukra * Venus
>
> Uttara-phalguni * Aryamna * Surya
>
> Hasta * Savitra * Chandra * Somana
>
> Chitra * Tvastri * Mangala
>
> Swati * Vayu Arcturus * Rahu
>
> Bishaja * Vishaka * Radha * Guru
>
> Anuradha * Maitra * Shani * Saturn
>
> Jyestha * Ketta * Budha * Mercury
>
> Mula * Alakshmi * Ketu
>
> Purvazadha * Apah * Shukra * Venus
>
> Uttara-azadha * Vaizva * Surya
>
> Shravana * Hari * Chandra * Somana
>
> Dhaniztha * Sravishtha * Mangala
>
> Shatavishaka * Shatatakara * Rahu
>
> Purva-bhadra-pada * Prosthapada Pegasus * Guru
>
> Uttara-bhadra-pada * Ahira-budhnaya * Shani * Saturn
>
> Revati * Pushan * Budha * Mercury

Taken from the website of *Barbara Pijan Lama*:  http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/Nakshatra_radical/nakshatra_main_page.htm

Comment: What is meant by 'professor'? (I didn't know that the devas had a part time job in a university? :p )

Comment: @Surya: lolol the lady is not Indian but has studied Jyotisha deeply, I will delete that term